# Load Assembly does not work for .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried

```
var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"path.to.dll");
Assembly o = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(@"path.to.dll"));
```

open assembly where I have Attributes to read but this two ways do not work in .net core 1.1 How in other way I can load it?

Comment: So what happens when you *do* try it? Do you get a compile-time failure? An exception? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The Assembly.**Load** Function Does Not Use a Path In Any Way as an Argument,
Therefore You Will Need To Use The Assembly.**LoadFile** Function,

For Example, I Copied a Random .dll From The System32 Folder To My Desktop,
And Then I Executed The Following Lines:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\TomerHorowitz\Desktop\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll");
Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
```

Output:

```
 Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
```

Comment: and show me in .net core method LoadFile. Because my VS 2017 said that 'Assembly' does not contain a definition for it

Comment: You can see the documentation for the .LoadFile Here:              https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and are you able to read? It is for .NET Framework and no, it is not work for core